# Capybara: how to fill in an input form with no id, name, or label text?

Tags: xml, capybara

I am trying to fill in the date field on a web page with the following using Capybara:

```
<div class="activity--history-custom-dates-filter-container">
  <label class="activity--header-element-label">From </label>
  <input class="activity--history-custom-date-field
       fid-datepicker--input activity-- history-custom-date-from-field hasDatepicker"
       placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" id="dp1416484110853">
  <button class="activity--calendar-button"></button>
</div>
```

I can get to the parent div with the following:

```
within :xpath, "//label[text()='From ']/.." do
  fill_in ????, with: period.first.american
end
```

I would like to fill in the input field with the date as shown, but I
can't seem to find the right 'locator' (shown as ????) as the first argument to
fill_in.  The id is generated programmaticly so it changes on each
visit to the page, so that's not acceptable.

The Capybara docs describe fill_in as follows:

"Locate a text field or text area and fill it in with the given text
  The field can be found via its name, id or label text."

Apparently, 'name' here means any text associated with the node, not
the name of the element 'input' here.

I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are limited to use `within` block? If not maybe do like this:

```
find(:xpath, "//label[text()='From ']/../input").set period.first.american
```

Comment: Thanks, Oleksii.  I came here to update my question to say that I found I could use .set on the node itself, but you beat me to it.  So you get the badge!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this in a prettier way with css as well, like so:

```
within '.activity--history-custom-dates-filter-container' do
  find('input').set period.first.american
end
```